# Update a gamer and its child objects using Entity framework 6.0

Tags: c#, role-playing-game, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The below logic is working fine. But is there any way to optimize this logic ?

Gamer is the root level object, it will have Characters. Character will have set of Skills & a weapon

I want to update the Gamer object along with its child objects

```
    public async Task UpdateGamerCharacterAsync(Gamer existingGamer, Gamer gamerToUpdate)
    {
        // Update Gamer
        this.DbContext.Entry(existingGamer).CurrentValues.SetValues(gamerToUpdate);

        // Delete children that are removed in the latest version
        foreach (var existingCharacter in existingGamer.Characters.ToList())
        {
            if (!gamerToUpdate.Characters.Any(c => c.Id == existingCharacter.Id))
            {
                this.DbContext.Weapons.Remove(existingCharacter.Weapon);
                this.DbContext.CharacterSkill.RemoveRange(existingCharacter.CharacterSkill);
                this.DbContext.Remove(existingCharacter);
            }
        }

        // Update and Insert children
        foreach (var characterToUpdate in gamerToUpdate.Characters)
        {
            var existingCharacter = existingGamer.Characters
                .Where(c => c.Id == characterToUpdate.Id && c.Id != default(int))
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (existingCharacter != null) // Update child
            {
                this.DbContext.CharacterSkill.RemoveRange(existingCharacter.CharacterSkill);
                if(existingCharacter.Weapon != null)
                    this.DbContext.Weapons.RemoveRange(existingCharacter.Weapon);
                this.DbContext.Entry(existingCharacter).CurrentValues.SetValues(characterToUpdate);
                if(characterToUpdate.Weapon != null)
                    this.DbContext.Weapons.Add(characterToUpdate.Weapon);
                this.DbContext.CharacterSkill.AddRange(characterToUpdate.CharacterSkill);
            }
            else // Insert child
            {
                existingGamer.Characters.Add(characterToUpdate);
                if (characterToUpdate.Weapon != null)
                    this.DbContext.Weapons.Add(characterToUpdate.Weapon);
                this.DbContext.CharacterSkill.AddRange(characterToUpdate.CharacterSkill);
            }
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**Playload:**

```
{
   "id":1,
   "username":"User-1 Updated 5",
   "characters":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Super Man Updated 5",
         "rpgClass":"Attacker",
         "weapon":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Knife Updated 5",
            "damage":100,
            "createdBy":"System",
            "createdDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033756Z",
            "lastModifiedBy":"System",
            "lastModifiedDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033756Z"
         },
         "characterSkill":[
            {
               "characterId":1,
               "skillId":1
            },
            {
               "characterId":1,
               "skillId":2
            }           
         ],
         "createdBy":"System",
         "createdDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033753Z",
         "lastModifiedBy":"System",
         "lastModifiedDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033753Z"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Wonder Women Updated 5",
         "rpgClass":"Attacker Updated 5",
         "weapon":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"Gun Updated 5",
            "damage":100,
            "createdBy":"System",
            "createdDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033757Z",
            "lastModifiedBy":"System",
            "lastModifiedDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033757Z"
         },
         "characterSkill":[
            {
               "characterId":2,
               "skillId":3
            },
            {
               "characterId":2,
               "skillId":4
            }           
         ],
         "createdBy":"System",
         "createdDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033753Z",
         "lastModifiedBy":"System",
         "lastModifiedDate":"2022-07-20T02:33:52.033753Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You say the code is working, but never describe what "working" means here.  What is it supposed to actually _do_?  Context and intent are really important when reviewing code!

Comment: As previously indicated, context is very important in a code review please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the section on the title. In this case if you are using SQL it might help if you posted the tables from the database as well, if you auto generated the data you may need to make some edits to the data tables.

Comment: Considering that some database engines would be able to remove large swathes of the manual cleanup process around dependent entities that you are doing by virtue of proper foreign key definitions, it would be very important to know what the database you are using is... Until that information is available it's very hard (i.e. impossible) to give advice that takes the real context of the code into account.